# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { while importing function from file

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I'm trying to create my own library to get the weather forecast, the problem is that i'm having problems with import of a function

I've already tried `export function convertDate ...` and it didn't work

Here is the error i get:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {convertDate} from "./utils/DataManagement";
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:696:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Here is how i import the function:

```
import {convertDate} from "./utils/DataManagement";
```

And finally here is where i have the function itself and also where i export it:

```
function convertDate(date) {
    let newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
    let offs = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    let hours = date.getHours();
    newDate.setHours(hours - offs);
    return newDate;
}

export { convertDate };
```

Comment: To use ESM modules in Node.js, you need `--experimental-modules` flag and `.mjs` extensions for files. See https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: do you use babel compiler ?

Comment: @eladBA no, i don't use any compiler, this is just pure javascript

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt even passing this option doesn't work, and i also get that ``require()`` is not defined

Comment: this is your problem import works only on es6 and you need compiler for this to work
here is a resource https://medium.com/recraftrelic/es5-vs-es6-with-example-code-9901fa0136fc#f0ab

Comment: What Node.js version do you use?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt 11.9.0 on mac

Comment: If I undesatand correctly: 1. All involved files should have `.mjs` extension, both main script and module. 2. I am not sure you can use both `import` and `require` in the same script.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use ES6 compiler to use import/export

without it you should use ES5 module.exports

here is a resource [resource](https://medium.com/recraftrelic/es5-vs-es6-with-example-code-9901fa0136fc#f0ab)

Comment: in the link you sent me does not mention any compiler

Comment: the link was to show you that it came out in ES6
It is well known that to use ES6 syntax in browser you have to use a compiler, you have BABEL compiler as example

Answer (score 0):

Setting up babel. 
[ https://babeljs.io/en/setup#browser ] 
If link don't work just copy and paste

Comment: Some explanation?

Comment: @shubham-tiwari i still have the same problem with this, i tried it before

Comment: Explanation [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export ]°°if link don't work copy and paste in browser